# rspec 'allow' stub isn't setting variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, stub

I have a controller function:

```
def update
    @simulation = Simulation.find(params[:id])
    @simulation.next
    puts "--"
    puts @simulation.dirty?
    puts @simulation.save

    if (@simulation.save && @simulation.dirty?)
        render :partial => 'show', :object => @simulation
    end
end
```

And an rspec test:

```
    it "should render a partial when the record is dirty" do 
        allow(@simulation).to receive('dirty?') { true }

        put :update, :id => @simulation.id, :format => 'js'

        expect(response).to render_template( :partial => 'show' )
    end
```

The test is failing to render the view because the if check isn't passing because it won't return true for @simulation#dirty? even though the function is stubbed. I can see this because of the puts in the controller. Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance variable `@simulation` you are stubbing does not belong to the controller instance, but to the rspec test case class instance. Try `@simulation.dirty?` within it block of rspec, after the allow method call. I guess it returns true. The `@simulation` in the controller is not stubbed, though. They are two different objects.

If you want to stub `@simulation` in the controller's update method, you should stub all the instance of the Simulation class. Try using allow_any_instance_of instead of `allow(@simulation`).

```
allow_any_instance_of(Simulation).to receive(:dirty?).and_return(true)
```

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#settings-mocks-or-stubs-on-any-instance-of-a-class

Comment: This gives me `NoMethodError:
       undefined method `ancestors' for #<Simulation:0x007fd0d1925a50>`

Comment: 2) SimulationsController PUT #update should render a partial when the record is dirty
     Failure/Error: allow_any_instance_of(@simulation).to receive(:dirty?).and_return(true)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `ancestors' for #<Simulation:0x007fd0d1925a50>

Comment: That is the full trace

Comment: Does your partial try to call `Simulation#ancestors`? Also, is `puts @simulation.dirty?` in your controller called? Does it prints true?

Comment: No calls to Simulation#ancestors

Comment: Getting false on @simulation.dirty? in the controller

Comment: Does `@simulation.dirty?` returns false even before `@simulation.next` ?

Comment: I got it, you where close.. it's `allow_any_instance_of(Simulation).to receive(:dirty?).and_return(true)` mind correcting your answer so I can accept ?

Comment: Seems identical but I replaced the line with yours.

Comment: its `Simulation` instead of `@simulation`

Comment: I think it was originally `allow_any_instance_of(Simulation)` since even though I replaced the line in the answer, SO doesn't say the answer is edited. But anyway, glad your problem is solved.